# Action values are not updating an instance when using Invoke

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an extension method using `Action` in ASP.NET Core 3.1:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseSitemap(this IApplicationBuilder builder, Action<(String BaseUrl, String Route)> options) {

  (String BaseUrl, String Route) sitemapOptions = ("", "/sitemap"); // Default values

  options?.Invoke(sitemapOptions);

  return builder.MapWhen(x => x.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(sitemapOptions.Route), x => x.UseMiddleware<SitemapMiddleware>(sitemapOptions));

}
```

Then I use it as follows:

```
  application.UseSitemap(x => { 
    x.BaseUrl = "https://locahost:80";
    x.Route = "/sitemap.xml"; 
  });
```

However, sitemapOptions is not getting the new values. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(String BaseUrl, String Route)` is actually a struct [`ValueTuple<T1,T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2?view=netcore-3.1), so it is passed by value to your `options` action and can't be updated this way:

```
public void Update((String BaseUrl, String Route) x)
{
    x.BaseUrl = "https://locahost:80";
    x.Route = "/sitemap.xml";
}

public void Update(ref (String BaseUrl, String Route) x)
{
    x.BaseUrl = "https://locahost:80";
    x.Route = "/sitemap.xml";
}


Update(sitemapOptions);
Console.WriteLine(sitemapOptions); // prints "(, /sitemap)"

Update(ref sitemapOptions);
Console.WriteLine(sitemapOptions); // prints "(https://locahost:80, /sitemap.xml)"
```